# Error with superset, oracle and SQL Lab no attribute tzinfo_factory

Tags: linux, oracle, apache-superset

I'm getting this error when run a query in SQL Lab in Superset:

> oracle error: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'tzinfo_factory'

I'm using:

- superset 0.30.1
- Python 3.7.4
- cx-Oracle 7.3.0
- Debian 9

But when I create a chart from a source made by a table, that's works fine.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem today, found [this issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/9216) with quickfixes

The fourth fix did the trick for me:

> Superset does not detect oracle and uses postgres specs for that datasource. So you need to comment this line to fix SQL Lab error
>
> superset/db_engine_specs/postgres.py +52
> # cursor.tzinfo_factory = FixedOffsetTimezone